# Rails query with delegate fields of a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rails-activerecord

Hi am having two models with has_one association. I need to search with delegate fields.

```
**Model 1:**
class Reservation < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :content
    delegate :type, :title, :to => :content
end

**Model 2:**
class Content < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :reservation
end
```

The following query works fine, because of delegate:

```
reservations = Reservation.last
reservations.title
 ~   Content Load (0.6ms)  SELECT `contents`.* FROM `contents` WHERE `contents`.`id` = 95 LIMIT 1
 => "Birthday Party"
```

Now i need to do query using delegate fields:

```
reservations = Reservation.where("title = ?","some_title")
```

it returns error:

```
Unknown column 'title' in 'where clause'
```

How can i solve the problem? is that am doing in correct way? Thanks for reading my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem can solved by using `joins` and `where`. But not sure if this is what you are looking for.

```
reservations = Reservation.joins(:content).where("contents.title = ?","some_title")
```

Comment: It will work. But its a good practice to use the table name as prefix because conflict will occur if Reservation also has the same column.

Comment: when i use table name as prefix its throwing this error: Mysql::Error: Unknown column 'content.title'